# Is it possible to use hyperledger with PouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, pouchdb

I have a working Hyperledger Fabric application with CouchDB (alternate state database that allows you to model data on the ledger as JSON). But my question goes one more level up to understand if it is possible to use pouchDB  with the above Hyperledger setup (eg. pouchdb setup with sync capabilities with CouchDB or so. I am not familiar much with pouchDB technicalities. Also not sure how Hyperledger supports PouchDB?

Any clarity or example would be helpful.

Comment: pouchDB fairly duplicates CouchDB functionality. pouchDB is not an application anymore than CouchDB is, so there is no reasonable answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

With Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.8 and Pouchdb 4.2.0

createChannel, joinChannel, Chaincode Install,
invoke, query

All was possible.

However, it cannot be used with the original version of PouchDB.

Among the modules of PouchDB

"expiress-pouchdb"

Some code needs to be modified.

Anyway it's possible